# Getting 400 bad request with GuzzleHTTP when trying to POST new product

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api, guzzle

I'm trying to use the /product endpoint but keep getting

```
`400 Bad Request` response:
{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"product"}}
```

My header includes the Json content-type. I'm really lost on how to form the body. Or does this even go in body? Below is my request:

```
<?php
require_once ('connparams.php');
$headers = [
    "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $token,        
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
];
$response = $client->request('post', 'products', 
["headers" => $headers],
["body" => 
["product" => 
        ["sku" => 12211]
]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$response = $client->request('post', 'products',
    $headers,
    [
        "product" => [
            "sku" => 12211
        ]
    ]
);
```

where `$headers` is an associative array.